# Nested DIVs don´t always have the same height

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I want to have one container div always in middle of site. It has fixed width and min-height. Inside this container (ContentWrapper) are two divs - one for content (left) and one for side-info (right). But when the left div contain a long text the right one should have the same height as the left-one. With this code Im unable to do this:

```
<div id="ContentWrapper">
    <div id="ContentLeft"></div>
    <div id="ContentRight"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#ContentWrapper {
background-color:aqua;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-top:100px;
width:1200px;
margin-left:-600px;
min-width:900px;
min-height:500px;
}

div#ContentLeft{
width:70%;
height:100%; 
background-color:#f1f1f1;
float:left;
border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
overflow: visible;
}

div#ContentRight{
width:30%;
height:100%; 
background-color:#dfdfdf;
float:left;
border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

Key properties:

Min-height for ContentLeft

Fixed width for ContentWrapper

ContentLeft must follow its containts height

ContentRight must follow ContainLefts height

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
div#ContentWrapper {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1200px;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: -600px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
div#ContentLeft {
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
div#ContentRight {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContentWrapper">
  <div id="ContentLeft"></div>
  <div id="ContentRight"></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KVazwe)

Comment: So far, this seems to be the way to go. I don´t know display:flex; so thanks for that

Comment: Could this solve problem with padding on ContentLeft? When I set padding:5px; ContentLeft get bigger. Is it posiible to set padding and keep DIV dimensions unchanged?

Comment: Sure you just need to set the box-sizing property to border-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want `div1` and `div2` side-by-side to end up the same height regardless of content.  You have a few options.

1) set the height of the divs and `overflow-y:scroll` or `overflow-y:hidden`

2) use `<table>`s

3) use `CSS` and set `display:table` `display:table-row` `display:table-cell`  --  NOTE This will fail in IE7 and under

4) I just thought of this .. You could also use `JavaScript` to detect the bigger `div` and set the div height of the sibling div to be equal.  Theoretically -- I've never tested it.

Comment: No scrolls, divs must strech with content but nested div must keep some min-height

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: table; for the parent div, and display: table-cell; for the two child divs, also remove float: left;
Here is the css adjusted, I have removed some of the properties for easier testing

```
div#ContentWrapper {
background-color:aqua;
position:absolute;
margin-top:100px;
width:200px;
min-width:300px;
min-height:10px;
display: table;
}

div#ContentLeft{
width:70%;
height:100%; 
background-color:#f1f1f1;
border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
overflow: visible;
display: table-cell;
}

div#ContentRight{
width:30%;
height:100%; 
background-color:#dfdfdf;
border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
display: table-cell;
}
```